How to use font awesome icons as bullet points in Quarto revealjs presentation?
I'm making a Quarto presentation and I'd like (for a bit of fun) to be able to use font awesome icons as bullet points. I have a css style sheet which I point my Quarto doc to on rendering. I don't really know much css but can often tinker enough with what I find online to make things work. However I can't really find an answer to how to do this. I have an unordered list with 4 levels and I've figured out how to amend my style sheet to change the type of bullet point at each level. The following works (the list types are just examples):
.reveal ul {
  list-style-type: lower-greek;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10;
}

.reveal ul ul {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10;
}

.reveal ul ul ul {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10;
}

.reveal ul ul ul ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10;
}

Is there a simple way to amend this to incorporate a (font awesome) icon as the style type?
Thanks.

You could also have a look at this question: Font Awesome doesn't change bullet points in revealjs Quarto

The following worked:
.reveal li {
  list-style-image: url('images/tree-solid.svg');
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10;
}


